# insert into db - apostrophe is inserted like this &#x27;

Tags: php, character-encoding, escaping

I'm trying to scrape some data with php. When inserting the data into mysql table (xampp) the appostrohe  appear like so - &#x27

How do I get rid of this characther.

I used addslashes and mysql_real_escape_string and I stell can't get rid of it..

Comment: "not working" is not an error message nor a problem description.

Comment: What type of table, an HTML table or a SQL table?

Comment: "no result" is not an error message nor a problem description.

Comment: I use the xampp packet, (mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to scrape some data with php. When inserting the data into table the appostrohe appear like so - &#x27

`&#x27;` **is** the proper HTML for an apostrophe. If you're scraping from someone's website, you're going to get their HTML, which in this case is apparently properly escaped.

You can run the text through `htmlspecialchars_decode()` if you want to convert HTML entities to plain-text.

Comment: I used htmlspecialchars_decode(), addslashes, html_entity_decode, mysql_real_escape_string and still can't get rid of it..

Comment: Is it truly `&#x27` or is it `&#x27;`? If it's missing the semicolon, nothing's going to automatically handle it - you'll have to `str_replace` it or something.

Comment: Yeah there is the semicolon, sorry I forget to write.